# java code if we want that only person which is authenticated in firebase can write while others can read which are not authenticated

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to make a app in which only the person who is authenticated in firebase by entering his email and password for the first time through the app can change or add the data/video in the firebase but other user who are not authenticated and are using the app can only read/watch the videos added by admin.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'userID'"
  }
}
```

The above is the firebase code. In simple words i just want to know that the `userId` will automatically will be replaced by the actual userId let say `'adjkekloudh'` or we need to write any code in java, If yes then what Please help

This is the java code that i used when the rules in the firebase are public are for everyone who is authenticated but i want that only the admin should remain authenticated and and user without authentication/loign/signup can watch the video.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button login;
    private Button signUp;
    private Button iamUser;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETemailaddressID);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETPasswordID);
        login =(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtnID);
        signUp =(Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpBtnID);
        iamUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iamUserID);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        //final DatabaseReference mref = database.getReference("message");

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if(user != null){
                    // user is singned in
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signed In",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    // user is not signed in
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No such user exists!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailString = email.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();

                if(!emailString.equals("") && !pwd.equals("")){
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailString,pwd)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong email or password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signed In",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                // we can now write to database

                               // Customer customer = new Customer("Disha","sonalname@gmail.com","Namdev",19);
                               // mref.setValue(customer);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadVideo.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
            }
        });

        iamUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowVideoActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(mAuthListener != null){
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Here signup button is for the admin/boss who will first time will enter his email and password and signIn button is again for the admin to add data in firebase and i_am_user button is for the user so that they can directly go to list of videos that admin had added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want any authenticated user to be able to write files, you can use

```
".write": "auth.uid != null"
```

I'd recommend making the rules a bit tighter to match your application logic in this case, as with the above anyone can sign in and replace/delete your entire database with one API call. The documentation for [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules) has some great examples for that.

---

If you only want a specific user to write files, you will need to know their UID and add that to your rule manually. This does not (and cannot) happen automatically.